# WPF to WCF Permission issue

Tags: wpf, wcf, security, permissions, service

I have created a WPF browser application that I wish to connect to a WCF service.  The service is in the same solution as the WPF application.  It is the default service that Visual Studio creates with a method called GetData (int)

I am attempting to call this service with the following code:

```
var client = new Service1.Service1Client();
client.GetData(10);
```

I get the following error on the above line (client.GetData(10);)

```
{"Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed."}
```

Please help

Comment: Does it work if you Run as Administrator?  open the bin/debug directory and right-click, Run as Administrator on the .exe

Answer (score 3):

This solution from Scott Lanford worked for me:
http://www.codeexperiment.com/post/Debugging-XBAPWCF-Applications.aspx

**Quote:**
The possible reasons for this error are numerous but in this case it was because the default Debug->Start Action for an XBAP project is "Start browser in URL", where the URL simply points to the .xbap file on disk (e.g. C:\projects\myproject\bin\debug\myproject.xbap).

For a partial trust XBAP application to communicate with a WCF service it must be deployed from the same domain and port as the WCF service. The way to solve this dilemma is to fake the XBAP URL by starting the XBAP application with PresentationHost.exe and supplying the XBAP URL (copied from the "Start browser with URL" value) via the debug parameter and the WCF service URL via the debugSecurityZoneURL parameter.

For example the debugging options for your XBAP project should look something like this:

**Start Action ->** Start external program = *%windir%\system32\PresentationHost.exe*

**Start Options ->** Command line arguments = *-debug "c:\projects\myproject\bin\debug\MyProject.xbap" -debugSecurityZoneUrl "http://localhost:2022"*

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a client access policy on the server. Running in the browser comes with a bunch of security limitations.

I think this article should get you the information you need, http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=208&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1.